# using std::shared_ptr with a pointer to member function

Tags: c++, pointers

With C pointers I can do somethnig like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class Foo {
     void bar(){
     std::cout<<"Hello from Foo::bar \n";
        }
   } 

void main(){
    Foo foo; 
    Foo* foo_ptr=&foo;
    std::shrared_ptr<Foo> foo_sptr(&foo);
    void (Foo::*bar_ptr)()=&Foo::bar;
    (foo.*bar_ptr)();
    (foo_ptr->*bar_ptr)();
    //(foo_sptr->*bar_ptr)(); // does not compile for me
```

If I want to use a smart_ptr instead of a C pointer, I get a compiler error:

```
error: no operator "->*" matches these operands
        operand types are: std::shared_ptr<Foo> ->* void (Foo::*)()
(foo_sptr->*bar_ptr)();
```

Is there a way to make this work without std::shared_ptr::get() ?

Comment: For function pointer you should use "std::function" in C++.

Comment: Live demo with `std::function`: http://ideone.com/vKsvXA

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The OP is not storing one there, they're trying to invoke the member function through a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @TiagoGomes Well, it does carry the overhead of dynamic allocation and a virtual call. Sometimes a pointer to member is all you need.

Comment: @Angew is the overhead in the creation of std::function or in the call ?

Comment: @MagunRa The dynamic allocation is in the creation of `std::function`. The virtual call is in its invocation.

Comment: @MagunRa: Allocation in the creation (although a good implementation will avoid this for small function objects), and a virtual call in the call.

Comment: @Agnew and Mike my question wasnt clear, I could guess when the overhead occurs. I my code I would creat it at the start and than call it many times, are the calls to `std::function` be slower than `get()`?

Comment: @Angew I don't think the virtual call inside `std::function::operator()` will be any worst than the indirection already used with the raw member pointer. I do agree the dynamic allocation, when small function object optimization don't kick in, may be undesirable though.

Comment: @MagunRa As I said, I don't believe there will be any noticeable performance change from calling with any of this two, as you already have a layer of indirection on the original solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` does not provide an overloaded `operator ->*`. So you have to use `get()`:

```
(foo_sptr.get()->*bar_ptr)();
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/XvaU2y)

Comment: I am aware of get() and that it works, but I have wonderd I it works without unwrapping the underlying pointer.

Comment: This answer is telling you that the answer is "no"

Comment: Kind of, Tiago Gomes answer is a other way around. But I got the enlightment I wanted from Angew and Tiago

Answer (score 0):

```
(&*foo_sptr)->*bar_ptr()
```

It's a bit ugly to look at but it would work for both shared_ptr and raw pointers.